# Class casting in virtual functions c++

Tags: c++

Hi I have the following piece of code -

```
class A{
public:
    A(){
        cout << "In A CTR" << endl;
       }

    virtual void buildTree() = 0;

    void print(){
    cout << "int A print  This = " << this << endl;
    }
};


class B{
public:
    B(){
        cout << "In B CTR" << endl;
    }
    virtual A* getBuilder() {
        cout << " In B getBuilder , this = " << this << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    virtual void hell(){
        cout << "In B hell This =" << this << endl;
    }
    void print(){
        cout << "in B print This = " << this << endl;
    }
    B* add(B* child){
        cout << "In B add , This = " << this <<endl;
    }
};

class C : public A, public B{
public:
    C(){
        cout << "In C CTR" << endl;
    }
    A* getBuilder() {
        cout << "In C getBuilder , this = " << this << endl;
        return this;
    }
    void print(){
        cout << "In C print  This = " << this << endl;
    }
};

class D : public C{
public:
    D(){
        cout <<"In D CTR" << endl;
    }
    void buildTree(){
        cout << "buildTree in D , This = "  << this << endl;
        B *b = NULL;
        add(b);
    }
    void print(){
        cout << "In D print  This = " << this << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
 B *root = new D();
 root->getBuilder()->buildTree();
 return 0;
}
```

I get the following output :

In C getBuilder , `this = 0x7f9aa0500100`

buildTree in D , `this = 0x7f9aa0500100`

In B add , `this = 0x7f9aa0500108`

I am unable to figure out , why the `add()` in `class B` is called . Here is my understanding . Please correct me.

`root` is a pointer of type `B` and points to `D` . 
So, when `root->getBuilder()` is called , it calls the virtual function in `class C` , which returns a pointer of type `A*` .

So, now `root->getBuilder()` returns a pointer of type A pointing to D. 
Hence `root->getBuilder()->buildTree()` is able to call buildTree in D .

But in the buildTree in `class D` , we are calling add which is defined in `class B`.
How are we able to call this , as the pointer type is `A` and should not know nothing about `B`, functions .

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Remember that inheritance is an "is-a" relationship. A `D` object is also a `B` object. `D` inherits `B::add` the normal way (through `C`).

Comment: Agreed , but suppose I have a funA() in class A, so D will inherit A::funA() , but if I do , say  B *root = new D();   root->funA().  I get an compiler error . How are these two different ?

Comment: Still not a problem. The class `D` will then have a `funA` becaise it inherits from `C` which inherits from `A`. Therefore `D` have a `funA` function. A `D` object is also an `A` object because of the inheritance.

Comment: Unrelated: there are no casts in this code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry , but why the complier error ?

Comment: The chain of calls `root->getBuilder()->buildTree();` does not change validity based on the *specific* `B` pointed to by `root`. It *so happens* that it is the same object *in this case*, but you can just as easily have a `class E : public A {/*whatever*/}; class F : public B { A* getBuilder() { return new E; } };` and then `B * root = new F; root->getBuilder()->buildTree();` does something different

Comment: Wait what? What compiler error? Perhaps you should try an ask another question if you get some build error (unrelated to this actual question which seems to be answered).

Comment: You can't move the *body* of `D::buildTree` into `A`, because `A` doesn't have `add`, `D` only has it via `B`. The call wouldn't get to `D::buildTree` if the most derived type of the object pointed to by `root` was `B`, because of the `return NULL` in `B::getBuilder`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP is talking about trying to call `A` members through the `B * root`. That fails for normal reasons. It's the confusion of `B::getBuilder` being overridden in `C` to `return this`. Static type vs dynamic type

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the question:

> But in the buildTree in class D , we are calling add which is defined
>   in class B. How are we able to call this , as the pointer type is A
>   and should not know nothing about B, functions.

Calling `buildTree` on a pointer type of `A*` where `buildTree` is marked as virtual is going to call buildTree on a `D*` given `root` is of type `D`. So `add` is available to `D` because `D` can access the public and protected methods of is superclasses.

The original code example is unnecessarily complicated. The same principle can be examined via the following code:

```
A *root = new D();
root->buildTree();
```

Comment: Hi Keith,  sorry couldn't get it . The root here is of type B* , and gets converted to type A* via getBuilder , how is it of type D*?

Comment: @user1999934, nothing get's converted. You are calling getBuilder which is implemented in class `C` as `return this` where `this` is a `D*`. So you are calling buildTree on an `A*` but it still points to a `D*`. You should create a simpler example if you don't understand virtual methods.

Comment: yeah I am in the process of learning virtual methods , but this is confusing to me . When you say where "this" is a D*, do you mean to say that "this" is a type D* and points to D or this is a type A* as the return type of getBuilder is A* and points to D.

Comment: The actual object is a `D`. When you call virtual methods on it, the runtime type of the object determines which implementation is used. Only the methods that belong to the static type (of the variable) are available to be called

Comment: @user1999934, you've created a `D` using the `new` operator. `D` is the only object created and in play. I think you might need to ask another question which is: why are the addresses different in your print outs - I suspect that's what is really confusing you.

Comment: @keith Can you tell me why it is :) ?

Comment: @user1999934 it's not straight forward, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398888/get-address-of-base-object-from-derived-object

Answer (score 1):

What you have is basically this (very simplified):

```
struct B
{
    B* add(B*)
    {
        std::cout << "B::add\n";
    }
};

struct C : B
{
    // Nothing relevant
};

struct D : C
{
    void buildTree()
    {
        add(NULL);
    }
};

int main()
{
    D root;
    root.buildTree();
}
```

The class `D` *is a* `C`. The class `C` *is a* `B`. That means `D` *is a* `B` as well. Therefore `D` has the member function `add`.

The pointers and indirection are red herrings in the case of how you can call `add` from a `D` member function.

---

I think I see the problem now, and it's about the interface the classes present to the world.

Again with a basic and simplified example:

```
struct A
{
    void funA();
}

struct B
{
    // Nothing relevant
};

struct C : A, B
{
    // Nothing relevant
};
```

Then by doing

```
B* p = new C;
```

is valid. But even though the pointer `p` is pointing to an object of `C` (which is also an `A`) it does not have the *interface* of `A` (or `C` for that matter), only of `B`.

If you want to use the functions in `A` or `C` you have to use *down-casting* to cast it to the correct type:

```
static_cast<D*>(p)->funA();  // Cast to the type `p` *really* is
```

Comment: I understand that add becomes a part of D . Maybe I am not able to make my question clear . Let me try again . Say I have a funA() in class A, so D will inherit A::funA() , but if I do , say B *root = new D(); root->funA(). This does not work . funA() is still is part of D . What am I missing here ?

Comment: @user1999934 Updated my answer.

Comment: got this . Now my original question . Say 
struct A   {virtual void buildTree() = 0; } 
struct B { void funB() } 
struct C : A,B { 
void buildTree() { funB() }
};  

A *ptr = new C();
ptr->buildTree();

Here buildTree is able to call funB, how can pointer ptr have the interface of B ?

Comment: @user1999934 Because `buildTree` is a member of `C`, which "is a" `B`.